# Looking for a proof without using Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a+b=r$, and let $l,m,n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $m<a$, $n<b$ and $l<r$.

Is there a way, **not using Archimedean Property**, to prove that for each $l$ there exist some $m$ and $n$ such that $m+n=l$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @lulu Sorry about that... I wonder if my wording was bad. So, for example, given $r=5 \in \mathbb{R}$, $a=2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b=3 \in \mathbb{R}$, if $l=4<5=r$ ($l$ always in $\mathbb{Q}$), I could let $m=1.6 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n=2.4 \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $m<a$, $n<b$ and $m+n=l$. Now, I want to prove the general case that for every such $a,b,r$, we can find some $m,n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for each such $l$. But I don't want to use Archimedean Property along the proof (somehow it seems inevitable for me right now...)

Comment: I deleted my prior comment because I figured out that you meant:  "Given real numbers $a,b,r$ such that $a+b=r$, if $l<r$ is a rational number, show that we can find rational numbers $m,n$ with $m<a, n<b$ and $m+n=r$."  I don't see how to avoid Archimedes (or something  equivalent to it).

Comment: @lulu I think in your last equation I would mean $m+n=l$ instead of $r$. Thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: Absolutely.  Thanks for spotting the typo.